# Calculate the arc length parametrization of a curve in terms of s(u)

Tags: vector-analysis, arc-length

Consider the parametrized curve **r**(u)=(5+u, 4u+7, 3u). Which one of the following functions is the arc length parametrization of the curve which starts from s=0 at the point (4,3,-3) along the curve?

I have calculated **r**'(u)= (1,4,3) and thus ||**r**'(u)||=√ 26.

However I'm confused on what to do next to find **s**(u). I understand there should be some sort of integration next wrt u and that would give [√ 26*u].

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The arc starts from $r(0)$ and ends in $r(-1)=(4, 3, -3)$. Hence the arc signed-length is the value of the integral
$$\int_0^{-1} \lvert r'(u)\rvert\,du=\int_0^{-1} \sqrt{26}\,du=-\sqrt{26}$$
Similarly when computing the area of regions bounded by graphs of functions, the definite integral takes signed values. Anyway, the arc length is $\sqrt{26}$

Comment: how does $r(1)=(4, 3, -3)$?

Comment: The question asks for it in the form of s(u) which is the parametrization form. Thanks for your help!

Comment: is the arc length parametrisation then $\sqrt{26}*u$